# How to display 'dummy' rows in ListView, on Android Studio Design display

Tags: android, android-studio, listview

This seems to me like a silly problem, however I searched for it and could not find an answer.  I am learning android development, following some tutorials online.  I am using ListViews right now, and in all tutorials, when they create a new, empty ListView, and place it within a ViewGroup, the 'design' view of Android Studio shows some 'dummy' rows, like that:

[image]

However, in my environment, the ListView is always empty in the AS design display.  I suspect this must be a setting within AS, but I can't find it.  Maybe it was 'on' by default, and in later versions it's disabled by default (I am using AS 3.6.1).  Most tutorials on ListViews are quite old anyway, I know RecyclerView is favoured, but I want to check some old tutorials for learning purposes.

I understand it's not very important, I populate my ListView programmatically anyway, and it works fine, but it's still annoying.  I could not find a way to display those 'dummy' rows on my AS design display.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: listview or recycler use adapter, and you need to inflate another layout for items, so how would your design know which child layout items you used, using include perhaps make sense for view

Comment: thanks for your reply. I 'm talking only about 'dummy' content - in other words, placeholders for rows, not real data - rows that only show something on the design display to help you understand how the real app will look like. I 've seen this on many tutorials - this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SLFrwl1hFcw for example, at 1.20. He just creates the listview, no items, no adapters, nothing, and design shows this 'dummy' content. Obviously if you 'd run the app, it 'd be blank. I hope you understand what I 'm talking about.